# Make text box only highlight text on first click only

Tags: c#, text

Currently I have it so that when you select the text box it will highlight the text in it but what I want it to do is only do this for the first time that it is selected so that it will not delete the text that the user is typing each time. Here is what I am using to highlight the text:

```
private void txtName_Focus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isFirstTime = true;
        if (isFirstTime == true){
        txtName.SelectionStart = 0;
        txtName.SelectionLength = txtName.Text.Length;

        }
        isFirstTime = false;


    }
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply add a `bool isFirstTime` to detect that? Then just reset the boolean as needed with your domain logic.

Comment: I added that but it did it for every time I attempted to type in the box but the first time.

Comment: Initialize it to `true` before using it and then `false` afterwards.

Comment: I think I'm missing something obvious here, I updated to what I thought was right but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bool isFirstTime = true;` this is your problem. It is being initialized to `true` *every time* the focus event is being called. Move `bool isFirstTime;` to be a member of your class and initialize it to `true` **once** in the declaration, constructor or the form load event

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
bool txtNameWasFocused=false;
private void txtName_Focus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!txtNameWasFocused){
        txtNameWasFocused=true;
        txtName.SelectionStart = 0;
        txtName.SelectionLength = txtName.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

If you need this in many places, you might think of a derived text box with this special behaviour...